# Ensure unique values in Entity Framework 7

Tags: entity-framework-core

I'm using Entity Framework 7 (beta). I want to constraint the values in a field, so no duplicate can be added.
With EF6 there was an Index markup which could be used like:

```
public class MyEntityClass
{ 
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    [MaxLength(10)]
    public string MyUniqueProperty{ get; set; } 
}
```

Sadly this attribute is not present in EF7 - how can I get EF7 to check for uniqueness?

Comment: For the time being: add the index manually I guess. By the way, this doesn't make EF check for uniqueness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data annotation is not available in beta8 see [roadmap](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Roadmap#in-progress)

You can set your checks in the onModelCreating
If you want to know what is supported add this reference in your project.json

```
    "EntityFramework.SqlServer.Design": "7.0.0-beta8",
```

And use scaffold from the command prompt

```
 dnx ef dbcontext scaffold "connectionstring" EntityFramework.SqlServer
```

example of generated code

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<LocalizationsOrg>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(e => e.Filename).HasDefaultValue("");

            entity.Property(e => e.LocaleId).HasDefaultValue("");

            entity.Property(e => e.ResourceSet).HasDefaultValue("");

            entity.Property(e => e.Type).HasDefaultValue("");

            entity.Property(e => e.Updated).HasDefaultValueSql("getutcdate()");

            entity.Property(e => e.Value).HasDefaultValue("");

            entity.Property(e => e.ValueType).HasDefaultValue(0);
        });

        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
```